# Fatal error: Index out of range when click specific cells for segue

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a segue so every time I click a tableView row, show another ViewController with the information of the specific row.

I populate my data from Firestore.

Basically every document contains an array and then I populate the strings of the array in rows

```
var ingredientsArray = [Ingredients]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return ingredientsArray.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ingredientsArray[section].compName.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SearchDetails", sender: self)
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientTableViewCell

        cell.populate(ingredient: ingredientsArray[indexPath.section])
        let item1 = ingredientsArray[indexPath.section].compName[indexPath.row]
        cell.ingredientNameLabel.text = ("\(item1)")

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController{

//HERE IS THE ERROR.
            destination.ingredient = ingredientsArray[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]

        }
    }
```

When I click some rows then my app crashes and gives me Fatal error: Index out of range

DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var compNameLbl: UILabel!

    var ingredient : Ingredients?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        compNameLbl.text = "\((ingredient?.compName)!)"


    }
}
```

Also when I try to show the name in the label the whole array appears.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I see that?

Comment: Use `destination.ingredient = ingredientsArray[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section)!]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I just had to change the row to section. One last thing when I click the row I want to show the name of the row in the `compNameLbl` but instead I get the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the string value from the `compName` array and pass the value

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destination.ingredient = ingredientsArray[indexPath.section].compName[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Change the `ingredient` type to `String` in `DetailViewController`

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet weak var compNameLbl: UILabel!
    var ingredient : String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        compNameLbl.text = ingredient
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thank you!